# DWORD,LPTSR,LPBYTE,HANDLE what do these terms mean?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, gdi

I came across these terms recently, while studying a program. I got an idea that they were *data types...?*

Are they really?

Could you please explain me what these terms really mean? I have not found their documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming context of Windows development, they are simply data types. See [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) (from Microsoft).

Answer (score 12):

> I have not found there documentation

Here it is:

- [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

All data types you mentioned are documented there. For your convenience:

- DWORD

  - A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.
  - This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows: `typedef unsigned long DWORD;`
- HANDLE

  - A handle to an object.
  - This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows: `typedef PVOID HANDLE;`
- LPBYTE

  - A pointer to a BYTE.
  - This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows: `typedef BYTE far *LPBYTE;`

And there is nothing `LPTSR`. There is `LPSTR`, and `LPTSTR` however.

Answer (score 2):

These are most commonly encountered as Microsoft-specific typedefs.

For instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230353(v=prot.10).aspx is an MSDN help page about `LPSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

For string/character related datatypes, you can refer:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc